# Localization of C# Windows Forms App doesn't work outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, localization

I got an old Windows Forms app (C# .net 2.0, VS 2010) and I need to make the localization works... there're already resource files with the translations.
Visual Studio shows me the resource files (.resx) expanding the form files with the name pattern: FormName.en-US.resx

The Build Action of them are "Embedded Resource" (what I assume must embed the resources inside my .exe, right?)

When I run the app from the Visual Studio it runs fine... and to change the language works as expected.
But when I install the app in the machine and try to run outside VS nothing changes when I change the language, and I got no clue about what's happening.

Some places says that I need to have a folder of the language (en-US in case)... but I assume this is only in case of a not embedded resource, right? Anyway, I tried to create the folder and copy the resources... no success.

I've tried to change the "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" to a lot of different things... nothing helps, and when I changed the Build Action to "Compile" I got some compile errors (maybe it's the cause? but how that works running from inside VS?)

Anyone has any clue about how to find out what's happening and fix it?

Comment: When you say "nothing changes when I change the language" - what do you mean specifically? ie how are you setting up the language to use?

Comment: I'm changing it setting the Culture for the language I want.
It works fine when I run the app from VS.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem actually was that I was thinking that "Embedded resource" meant that the resource would be embedded in the .exe, but it was in a dll, so I'd to copy this dlls to the right folder.